# Where is the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have just installed QGIS 2.6 and have installed the OpenLayers plugin. It lists the OpenLayers plugin in the installed tab, however, I can't add a layer to my project as it does not give the option to add an OpenLayers layer as previous versions do.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you're looking under the *"Web"* menu in the main QGIS window. The plugin layers should be listed under an OpenLayers submenu. (These options have moved since earlier versions).

Comment: If you don't have a Web menu, look under `Installed` plugins if the Openlayers plugin is checked. It gets unchecked whenever you have started an earlier version of QGIS 2.0 or 2.2.

Comment: @DeborahDarcy please consider to accept the answer if it was helpful for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Oh that was my problem too, and you are exactly right. I was going crazy trying to find the Google Satellite open plugin map under plugins (having worked with it in QGIS 2.2) and never thought to look under web in the top menu. What a relief.

Comment: I just installed it in QGIS 2.1.4-Essen. It's not under Plugins and it's not under Web. It is installed, according to the plugin manager. Not seeing it elsewhere. Anyone know where it is?

Comment: Just use the "QuickMapServices" plugin instead. It's replaced the old, deprecated OpenLayers plugin.